# Insertar iconos en string

Tags: python, telegram

Trabajo con la libreria de telethon en python para recibir y enviar mensajes a mi canal.

Mi idea es recibir en el canal un string con formato json(OJO: No es json!!! es string)

Y darle un formato mas legible, con lo cual me gustaria aparte de limpiar el json, que ya lo he conseguido:

```
def reemplazar(o_text):
    e_text = o_text
    for k, v in replace_words.items():
        e_text = e_text.replace(k, v)
    return e_text
```

Quisiera añadirle iconos, he probado con unicode, hexadecimal y otros formatos de iconos que supuestamente tendria que ser capaz de pintar, pero a la hora de enviar el mensaje lo mas que consigo es que pinte caracteres raros ( o simples ) pero no un icono como tal.

Con lo cual mi pregunta pasa a ser, esto es posible? estoy pasandole mal los iconos? Solo quiero definir 5 o 6 iconos para diferenciar los diferentes parametros que me llegan del json.

Ejemplo:

```
{
  "Partido": "Madrid - Barça",
  "Deporte": "Football"
}
```

Que quede asi:

```
:earth_africa: Partido: Madrid - Barça
  Deporte: :soccer: Football
```

(Aqui en so no me muestra los iconos, eso seria el texto como tal, pero tampoco me lo transforma) 
Tambien probe con la libreria de emoji,emojize (por si alguien me lo propone), pero tampoco consigo insertar el icono donde quiero.

Muchas gracias de antemano por su atención.

Saludos.

Comment: No entiendo un par de cosas. Primero tu nota "Ojo, no es JSON, es string". Todo JSON es en realidad string, sólo que un string con un cierto formato, que es al que llamamos JSON. Segundo, tampoco entiendo la salida que deseas. ¿Tiene que ser también formato JSON? (tu ejemplo no lo es), ¿o una cadena, vamos a decir, "normal"? En tu ejemplo esa cadena ocupa dos líneas y parece tener una indentación en la segunda. ¿Es así como lo quieres? Finalmente, entiendo que quieres meter el emoji, por ejemplo, donde pone `:soccer:` que salga ⚽, ¿no?

Comment: Pongo lo de OJO es string, porque en otro post que publique con otro problema distinto, me propusieron ejemplos de funciones que tratan json (json.loads) cuando realmente como indico, solo digo lo de json para dejar claro que es el formato que tiene, pero es un string normal como bien entendiste. Sobre la indentación es indiferente ya que no trato eso, simplemente lo recibo cambio lo que quiero y lo vuelvo a enviar, puedo poner el diccionario si lo deseas para que lo entiendas mejor. Y para terminar, efectivamente es lo que quiero, meter el emoji en vez del texto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según entiendo tras las aclaraciones en los comentarios, el hecho de que el contenido de la cadena sea JSON es irrelevante, y el formateo interno de la cadena ya lo manejas tú.

La pregunta se limita por tanto a cómo insertar en la cadena emojis, por ejemplo, cambiar las apariciones de la subcadena `"Football"` por `"⚽ Football"`.

En este caso la respuesta es directa, y probablemente ya lo hayas intentado y si no te ha funcionado deberías dar más detalles de qué esperabas y qué has obtenido.

La solución directa es usar `replace()` e incluir el emoji como parte del texto de reemplazo, es decir:

```
txt = "Partido: Madrid - Barça\nDeporte: Football"
txt = txt.replace("Football", "⚽ Football")
txt = txt.replace("Partido", " Partido")
print(txt)
```

```html
 Partido: Madrid - Barça
Deporte: ⚽ Football
```

Sí, puedes incluir emojis directamente dentro de una cadena Python. Basta que los busques en internet, por ejemplo en [emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/), los selecciones y los pegues en tu editor. Gracias al estándar Unicode, un emoji no es sino un carácter más, como puede serlo `A` o `ñ`.

Otra alternativa es, si conoces el código Unicode el emoji correspondiente, que lo insertes con la cadena de escape `\uXXXX` (si el código Unicode es de cuatro cifras hexadecimales) o `\UXXXXXXXX` (si es de más de 4, fíjate que en este caso la U es mayúscula y debes poner 8 cifras, aún si las tres primeras suelen ser ceros), dentro de la cadena Python. En nuestro caso, la pelota es el código U+26BD (no es por tanto un emoji propiamente dicho, pues éstos tienen códigos de cinco cifras), y el planeta centrado en África es el código U+1f303 (sí es un emoji). Por tanto:

```
txt = "Partido: Madrid - Barça\nDeporte: Football"
txt = txt.replace("Football", "\u26BD Football")
txt = txt.replace("Partido", "\U0001F30D Partido")
```

Aunque la forma de introducirlo es diferente (y el codigo fuente queda más *chulo* en el primer caso), a la hora de imprimir la cadena saldrá lo mismo.

Ahora bien, si se trata de enviar esta cadena a un canal Telegram, entiendo que la API que se ocupe de ello tendrá que recodificar los caracteres no ASCII usando por ejemplo UTF8, y el cliente que los reciba, además de decodificarlos, tendrá que tener la fuente adecuada para poder mostrarlos, así que si algo no te ha funcionado bien probablemente el problema esté en la parte cliente. Serían necesarios más detalles.

Comment: Te prometo que he probado a pegar directamente los iconos en pycharm y no me aparecian ni queriendo. Efectivamente poniendolos sin mas el icono en el .py si que los pinta. Y gracias a tu explicación, ya he entendido que es lo que hacia mal. yo de internet cojia \u+1F3BE (por ejemplo) entiendo que no puede llevar el +, y si es unicode tienen que ser 4 caracteres solo, por eso me pinta caracteres extraños. Muy bien explicado, muchisimas gracias @abulafia.

Comment: He de decir que los iconos de 5 cifras si que no me los pinta, por ejemplo el planeta tierra si pongo esto tanto en python como yml: \u1f303 me sale esto: " ἰ3 " realmente parece que solo es capaz de pintar los iconos si son 4 cifras u 8 digitos ya que si pongo la otra forma que pusiste: \U0001F30D si que lo pinta, sabrias decirme porque? solo por curiosidad

Comment: Porque el escape `\u` espera sólo 4 cifras detrás. Si pones `\u1f303`, en realidad estás diciendo el caracter unicode U+1f30, y luego el ascii "3". El primero resulta ser la [letra iota minúscula del griego](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f30/index.htm), que se parece mucho a una `i`, por eso ves `ἰ3`. Para usar códigos de más de cuatro cifras, hay que usar la `\U`, pero esta espera ocho cifras. El por qué de 8 supongo que es porque internamente se almacena en un entero de 32 bits, pero realmente Unicode sólo necesita 21 bits, por eso hay muchos ceros por la izquierda.

Comment: En definitiva para usar iconos de 5 cifras, meto 3 0 delante y listo no?

Comment: Sí, y la `\U` mayúscula.

Comment: Excelente!!!! Esta manera tan sucia ya podian decirla mas a menudo por los foros x) muchisimas gracias en serio. :)